# Regex to exclude certain file extensions

Tags: regex

similar questions have been asked, but they miss one thing I need to do and I can't figure it out.

I need to find all files that do NOT have either a tif, or tiff extension, but I DO need to find all others including those that have no extension. I got the first part working with the regex below, but this doesn't match files with no extension.

```
^(.+)\.(?!tif$|tiff$).+$
```

That works great, but I need the following to work.

```
filename.ext MATCH
filename.abc MATCH
filename.tif FAIL
filename     MATCH
```

Thanks :)

Comment: For which language is it?

Comment: Do you have some files in a directory or some strings in a text file?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not working with JS/ECMAscript regex, you can use:

```
^.*(?<!\.tif)(?<!\.tiff)$
```

Comment: Indeed I overdid it. Lookbehinds are still incredibly counter intuitive to me when they do nothing like a look BEHIND. Maybe you should add `\.` to the lookbehinds though, as right now they won't match `boring_filename_ending_with_tif`as they should.

Comment: @CyrilLemaire What do you mean? That's exactly what they do. Keep in mind that they look behind the current position that the regex engine is evaluating. Where it really starts to get crazy is when you nest lookbehinds inside of lookaheads (et al.).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a negative regex, consider using the simpler, positive regex, but taking action when something *does not* match.  This is often a superior approach.

It can't be used in every situation (e.g. if you are using a command line tool that requires you to specify what *does* match), but I would do this where possible.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
^(?:(.+\.)((?!tif$|tiff$)[^.]*)|[^.]+)$
```

That regex is split in two different parts:

**Part 1:** `(.+)\.((?!tif$|tiff$)[^.]*)`

- `(.+)` *(1st capturing group)* Match a filename (potentially containing dots)
- `\.` Match the last dot of the string (preceding the extension).
- `((?!tif$|tiff$)[^.]*)` *(2nd capturing group)* Then check if the dot is **not** followed by **exactly** "*tif*" or "*tiff*" and if so match the extension.

**Part 2:** `[^.]+` If part 1 didn't match, check if you have just a filename containing no dot.

Comment: Good luck with `filename.bak.tif`

Comment: Woops you're right I forgot about those, I'm back when I corrected that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some strings in a text file **( that has newline )**:

```
perl -lne '/(?:tiff?)/ || print' file
```

If you have some files in a directory:

```
ls | perl -lne '/(?:tiff?)/ || print'
```

**Screen-shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
^[^\.\s]+(\.|\s)(?!tiff?)
```

Explanation:

Beginning of line to dot or whitespace, put your matching group around this, ie:

```
^(?<result>[^\.\s]+)
```

It will then look for a dot or a whitespace, with a negative lookahead on the tiff (tiff? will match to both tif and tiff).

This makes the assumption that there will always be a dot or a whitespace after the filename. You can change this to be an end of line if that is what you need:

```
^[^\.\s]+(\.(?!tiff?)|\n)   linux
^[^\.\s]+(\.(?!tiff?)|\r\n) windows
```

Comment: `[^\.|\s]` will actually match any character that is **not** a `.`, a `|` or a whitespace. I'm not sure whether you meant to match anything but dots and whitespaces (`[^.\s]`) or I just didn't understand you at all.